# Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience is invalid" calling a secure ASP.NET Core 3 web API after login with Azure AAD

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, bearer-token

I am securing my webAPI in an ASP.NET Core 3 project to control access to it from an Angular frontend application.

I have registered the web API

[image: registered]

In appsettings.json I have this

```
  "AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "TenantId": "xxxxxxx",
  "ClientId": "xxxxxx",
  "Audience": "api://xxxxxx/acceso_como_usuario"
```

},

In the Startup.cs class I have this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
   services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration);
   services.AddAuthorization();
  }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
  {
      app.UseCors("default");
      app.UseHttpsRedirection();
      app.UseRouting();
      app.UseAuthentication();
      app.UseAuthorization();
  }
```

And in the controller this

```
namespace api.Controllers
{
 [Authorize]
 [Route("proyectos")]
```

From my Angular app authentication is done using Azure AD so before making any calls to my webAPI I log in

[image: login]

But calling any method or controller action gives me  error

I get the access token well before to make the call I get this error

WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience 'xxx' is invalid"

[image: audience]

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: [Does this answer useful to you?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/762957/www-authenticate-bearer-error34invalid-token34-err.html) It seems the same issue, and the op in that post have accepted it.

Comment: @JasonPan Sorry but that answer that answer didn't solve my problem

Comment: Please copy the Url after the login jump to me, be careful to hide confidential information. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qowAu.png

Comment: https://localhost:5001/api/proyectos/empleado/105/estado/abiertos

Comment: I'm sorry, I want the url is ` login.microsoft.com/... 'at the beginning,

Comment: It is recommended that you read these two posts carefully, which covers how to use aad, including some settings. [post 1:Azure AD Authentication with .NET Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70978170/azure-ad-authentication-with-net-core-web-api),  [post 2:Bearer token: The signature is invalid - Default ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web Api template published to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57953357/bearer-token-the-signature-is-invalid-default-asp-net-core-2-1-web-api-templa)

Comment: I have replicated the code of this example https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/blob/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api/README.md that works perfectly in my project and now the error I get is a 403, it seems that the access token and its signature are already validated but not completely

Comment: I have replicated this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70978170/azure-ad-authentication-with-net-core-web-api in my project and now the error is invalid audience when the aud claim is It is the one that I copied and pasted from the azure portal and scp claim the same too

Comment: Hi, @kintela, try to put in Audience your app Id in appsettings.json, not URL. It should be like "Audience":"API://{clientId}". Also, you can try to use Microsoft.Identity.Web library and configure it by calling next method:    services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(configuration, "AzureAd"/*,subscribeToJwtBearerMiddlewareDiagnosticsEvents: true*/);

Comment: @Serhii I have done but the same error The audience is invalid

Comment: Have you tried to deserialize your token(for ex. with jwt.io) and compare aud claim from token with Audience in appsettings?

Comment: @Serhii thank you so much, this actually your comment was my solution